# The functions tag seems to be misused

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions

It's being used for both questions about a theme's functions.php file, as well as for generic usage regarding anything to do with PHP functions. This should be separated out into two tags, functions and functions.php, indicating the difference. Questions revolving about theme's functions.php files come up often enough to deserve their own tag.

Note that the function synonym should probably point to the functions tag.

Comment: If it would be only that one...

Comment: Great to have you here as an active/regular community member Otto.. :)

Answer (score 3):

[function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) does point to [functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions).

[functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions.php) points to [functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) at moment. It was created by hakre and I don't remember if I participated or saw the reasoning for it at the time.

I am not sure the *functions* tag wanted in a sense of PHP functions. Everything about PHP takes functions. You can't have code without functions.

Also I am not sure that *functions.php* is tag-worthy. There isn't much to it itself. Of course there are plenty things that go there, but file itself is not that complicated of a concept or source of many issues.

I am not against current setup but I see it has a weak spots in logic. Open to discussion and suggestions.

Comment: agreed, a [functions] tag referring to PHP functions is spectacularly useless.. probably best to clarify in the tag wiki or rename the tag to it clearer.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood after some more thought `functions` does make sense as "question about WordPress functions". Functions choice and usage in context of WordPress-specific is important (if not essential) topic. But then I don't see how to cleanly decouple these from `functions.php`, both are mashed together under `functions` thanks to synonym.

Comment: I think there are (some) questions that can benefit from a `functions.php` tag: [Between functions.php, widgets and plugins, which is loaded first?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537), [How often is functions.php loaded?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3136), ... `functions` when talking about WordPress-specific functions might be better if called `wp-functions`. Currently I suggest breaking the synonym from `functions.php` to `functions`, and start using `wp-functions`. Those with courage can clean up the old `functions` tags.

Comment: @Jan Fabry I think `wp-functions` is confusing because of `wp-*` folders and `wp-admin` commonly used to describe admin area. It looks like core concept, but it wouldn't be.

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy to ditch [functions] entirely and make [functions.php] the main tag. The functions.php file is an important part of themes, and questions surrounding it are legit. "functions" in terms of PHP functions is a pretty darned useless tag to have.